# What free software can I use to edit RAW files?

Tags: software-recommendation, raw-format

I badly need to edit graphic file that unfortunately comes in some weird RAW format. The thing is that it seems that there's no freeware/open source software that could do such thing. Until now I've tried:

- Paint.Net with DCRaw plugin - it doesn't open the file + error prompt
- Gimp with UFRaw plugin - it doesn't open the file + error prompt
- RawTherapee - it doesn't open the file and no error prompt
- IrfanView - it DOES OPEN the file and it even seems to edit it, but saved file turns into "graphic gibberish"

The file is definitely not broken, since IrfanView opens it.

Question is - is there any free software that can edit RAW files?

Comment: IrfanView probably opens the embedded preview. Can you chek the image dimensions obtained this way?

Comment: What is a RAW file? As far as I understand, it's a generic name for ... values? Pixels? RGB, per line or channel separated? Does it have a width and height? And so on. Perhaps that's why there is no "universal" editor.

Comment: @Rad [RAW](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) is an image format usually from cameras that contains a lot of unprocessed sensor data.

Comment: @Cai: but other than its extension, there is no  *common* file type, right? As in, every camera has its own "raw" format?

Comment: @Rad to an extent yes, but its not like you need different software to process each type, most software that supports RAW will process most common RAW files (from my limited experience and understanding anyway), although it's possible OP has an obscure type that needs some proprietary software

Comment: @Cai: so this question cannot be answered as it is. It appears OP's files are not of the relatively common type(s), and without knowing at least what they were produced with, we can't help.

Comment: @Rad Probably. Although an answer explaining that with some possibilities would be helpful.

Comment: If it were me, I would simply ask the provider of the image to resend a tif or jpg. If they're sending out raw files, they probably don't completely understand  how to send images.

Comment: Would you post the first few lines of a hex dump of the "weird format" file?  e.g., the result of "od -c file.raw | head -4" or "xxd file.raw | head -4"

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to simply covert the files and then use them in Photoshop? I've used this here app to convert .raw files to .jpegs: https://raw.pics.io/
(I think I had to pay a few bucks and it was a bit of a clumsy app but it did the trick :)

Comment: Photoshop is not [Free Software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html).